# I am trying to find a clip about the art of old computer graphics

Tags: rendering, lighting, performance, optimisation, 2d-graphics

I have saw a clip where a guy talked about the art of squeezing some nice graphics into a very small space that was available on old computers. Come to think of it, it sounded something like today's git, where the changes were being saved, between the scenes, and the way it was rendered on screen. I have been searching for hours on YT and google and I couldn't find it, please help.

The game was from 80's or early 90's, and the scene I vaguely remember is a car parking in front of a building (probably a bar or a house) at night. The graphics was pretty dark, it was dark blue, indigo or purple, or some shades of those, but the headlights were bright yellow I think. The thing I remember about the clip was describing this scene in much detail, how it would use much more space if not for nifty tricks used by programmers.

I have tried searching google and YT for this keywords: old, game, noir, adventure, mystery, car, graphics, compression, methods, space, techniques, etc. Google didn't give me a screenshot I could recognize, I am not sure if it was YT or an example in a tutorial about computer graphics on some learning platform, sorry.
I even tried drawing the scene and searching by image on google, didn't help. Here is my drawing.

[image]

It was a great clip and inability to find it again is driving me mad, please help me if what i described seems familiar, that clip is a keeper really, I think most of the people here would enjoy it.
Thanks

Comment: Since you are asking for an old computer game, maybe your chances to get an answer are higher if you ask on [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) since they have a larger community. I can contact the mods on the site and migrate the question if they think your question is on-topic there and you agree.

Comment: Hi, @wychmaster, thank you for your help. I am new here so I am not that familiar with how things work, i.e. does migration mean it will be removed from [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/)? I am not sure about the tradeoff between the bigger community and being on-topic. It is more on-topic here but I understand that a bigger community might make the difference. In case it mustn't be in both places at once, I would like for it to be here for a week before migration if that's ok?

Comment: Migration means completely moving the question to another community. So it wouldn't be here anymore, but it was just a suggestion, so we can leave it on this site. In case you want it moved in the future, write another comment addressing me with `@` so that I get a notification.